# setInterval not good on mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, timer

So I am making a Javascript timer app. I am developing it in my spare time at home on a PC (in linux) and a friend is also testing it on a windows environment. Both of these seem fine but at work I use a mac and am testing it there. I just have it open in a separate tab in chrome while I'm doing my thing but I also update the title with the elapsed time so I can see it without having to switch tabs.

On the mac I am looking at the timer and it seems very inconsistent but only when I dont have that tab open...If im looking at the page tick away its 100% fine but when I have another tab open then its obviously not counting seconds normally. It seems to stop for about 2 seconds and then sometimes catches up on the next second by ticking twice and sometimes it doesnt. Either way I have been using it all day today while working for about 6 hours now and there is only about 4 hours on the clock.

The mac is fairly new (They bought it and I unboxed it and set it up myself less than 6 months ago) so im pretty sure its not running low on system resources or anything like that...its generally not obviously slow in any other way.

Its a pretty standard javascript setInterval call: setInterval(function, 1000);

And the only OS it seems to not work on or have this issue in is OSX. Any thoughts as to why this is? Should I start building the timer from scratch using setTimeout instead? (I am really wanting to avoid this as I have already been down this road and had issues...)

Thanks!

Comment: plenty of questions on stackoverflow about timers not being accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just use `setInterval` to make a timer, you need to instead calculate the elapsed time between **start** and **end** every time the `setInterval` callback function is called.

The time is accurate because it's calculated from two times. The start time and an X time. We subtract both times, and get the seconds that have have elapsed.

Even if you're tabbed out and performace is reduced for your unactive tab, we still have the original time memorized, so when you switch back to the tab, we can update the timer accordingly.

```js
var timer = function(elem){
  //Auto instantiate timer.
  if(!(this instanceof timer)){
    return new timer(elem);
  }

  //elem where results are shown.
  this.elem = elem;

  //Initial time set to null
  this.init = null;
  //Paused time set to null
  this.paused = null;
  //SetInterval code set to -1
  this.si = -1;
  //Offset set to 0 (used to calculate the resumed time after a pause)
  this.offset = 0;
}

timer.prototype = {
  start: function(){
    //If the tiemr is running, no point in trying to start it.
    if(this.si > -1 && this.init !== null){
      alert("Can't restart, stop it first.");
      return;
    }
    //Create start time.
    this.init = new Date();
    this.resume();
   
  },
  //Reset all values.
  stop: function(){
    this.init = null;
    this.paused = null;
    this.offset = 0;
    this.pause();
    this.si = -1;
  },
  pause: function(){
    //Remember the paused time, so that we can calculate the offset when we resume.
    this.paused = new Date();
    //stopping the timer.
    clearInterval(this.si);
    this.si = -1;
  },
  resume: function(){
    //if it's running we don't try to resume.
    if(this.si > -1){
      alert("Can't resume, pause/start it first.");
      return;
    }
    
    //if there is a pause time, then we calculate the offset.
    if(this.paused !== null){
      this.offset = Math.floor(((new Date()).getTime() - this.paused.getTime())/1000) + this.offset;
      this.paused = null;
    }
    //Create the timer.
     this.si = setInterval(function(){
       var tick = new Date();
       var elapsed_time_in_seconds = (tick.getTime() - this.init.getTime())/1000;
       this.print(Math.floor(elapsed_time_in_seconds-this.offset));
    }.bind(this), 100);
  },
  print: function(elapsed){
    this.elem.innerHTML = elapsed;
  },
  bindPause: function(elem){
    elem.onclick = function(){
      this.pause();
    }.bind(this);
  },
  bindResume: function(elem){
    elem.onclick = function(){
      this.resume();
    }.bind(this);
  },
  bindStart: function(elem){
   elem.onclick = function(){
      this.start();
    }.bind(this);
  },
  bindStop: function(elem){
    elem.onclick = function(){
      this.stop();
    }.bind(this);
  }
}

var timer1 = timer(document.getElementById('time1'));
var timer2 = timer(document.getElementById('time2'));
var timer3 = timer(document.getElementById('time3'));
var timer4 = timer(document.getElementById('time4'));

timer1.bindPause(document.getElementById('pause1'));
timer2.bindPause(document.getElementById('pause2'));
timer3.bindPause(document.getElementById('pause3'));
timer4.bindPause(document.getElementById('pause4'));

timer1.bindResume(document.getElementById('resume1'));
timer2.bindResume(document.getElementById('resume2'));
timer3.bindResume(document.getElementById('resume3'));
timer4.bindResume(document.getElementById('resume4'));

timer1.bindStart(document.getElementById('start1'));
timer2.bindStart(document.getElementById('start2'));
timer3.bindStart(document.getElementById('start3'));
timer4.bindStart(document.getElementById('start4'));

timer1.bindStop(document.getElementById('stop1'));
timer2.bindStop(document.getElementById('stop2'));
timer3.bindStop(document.getElementById('stop3'));
timer4.bindStop(document.getElementById('stop4'));

timer1.start();
timer2.start();
timer3.start();
timer4.start();
```

```html
Timer1: <div id="time1"></div>
Timer2: <div id="time2"></div>
Timer3: <div id="time3"></div>
Timer4: <div id="time4"></div>

<button id="pause1">Pause 1</button>
<button id="pause2">Pause 2</button>
<button id="pause3">Pause 3</button>
<button id="pause4">Pause 4</button>
</br>
<button id="resume1">Resume 1</button>
<button id="resume2">Resume 2</button>
<button id="resume3">Resume 3</button>
<button id="resume4">Resume 4</button>
</br>
<button id="start1">Start 1</button>
<button id="start2">Start 2</button>
<button id="start3">Start 3</button>
<button id="start4">Start 4</button>
</br>
<button id="stop1">Stop 1</button>
<button id="stop2">Stop 2</button>
<button id="stop3">Stop 3</button>
<button id="stop4">Stop 4</button>
```

Comment: Ok...so just let me know if I got this correctly...here you arent actually using the setInterval to count but instead using it to update the elapsed_time_in_seconds var somewhat regularly? Freaking genius! This could be exactly what I'm looking for! I'm not gonna mark this as correct just yet...gonna test it out and see how it goes but I think this could be a winner!

Comment: Although I just had a thought...my timer is slightly more in-depth that I originally explained. What I am doing is creating up to 4 timers as objects so I need to be able to pause and resume them each as and when I please...I can't see a way to do that right now but im gonna have a play around and see how I get on although I am open to suggestions...

Comment: lol! that was quick haha...im gonna have to give that all a good read and figure out what the hell is going on but it's looking good! Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: I was just playing around with the fiddle on here and it alerts an error when I click resume after pausing the first time saying I need to stop/pause it before i can resume. :/ It's deffo progress though! thanks again!

Comment: Almost...im just using the pause and resume buttons here but when you pause it and leave it for 10 seconds or so and then click resume it jumps up about 8 seconds so theres still something missing...I am also playing around with this...we are so close I can taste it!

Comment: @MatthewJonat fixed it as well.

Comment: So you did! Amazing! Now I just gotta convert this into the way im already calling objects and I'm golden! As in calling a new object in the way of var timer1 = new Timer(elem); I think I should be able to take it from here although the one thing im not properly understanding here is the .bind you are using... Anyways...thanks again!! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @MatthewJonat, the bind is simply to link (for example) the pause 1 button to your timer1 insance. This way when you click the pause button, the pause function of your timer1 will be called. No worries, good luck.

Comment: @MatthewJonat if you're refering to the `.bind(this)` ... As you can see inside the `function(){}.bind(this);` .. I call for example  `this.pause();`... if I didn't have bind(this) the `this` inside the function would not reference the timer instance but something else, and thus `this.pause()` would create an error.

Remove, `.bind(this)` and add a `console.log(this);` inside the function. And you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. When a tab isn't in focus, it shouldn't need realtime attention from the processor.

Instead, your timer should ideally "sleep". Personally, I weave the timer with `requestAnimationFrame` so that things only execute when the tab is in focus - this has the neat effect of allowing the user to see the update happen before their eyes.

Also, with any kind of timer, you should never use `setInterval(..., 1000)` and expect it to be *exactly* 1000 milliseconds. Instead, use `Date.now()` to figure out how much time has actually passed, and update accordingly.

Comment: I did look into using requestAnimationFrame but the official documentation ony really spoke about smaller time scales and basically referred specifially to using it for animations whereas I wanna create a timer that lasts potentially 8 - 12 hours or so...would you still recommend this for this?

Comment: The general idea is `function loop() {setTimeout(function() {requestAnimationFrame(function() { doTheThing(); loop(); })},1000);} loop();` - this will create a time loop.